# Get role in controller symfony2 FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

How can i know the roles of my personel.

```
$personal = $em->getRepository('AuthenticationBundle:User')->FindPersonel($id);    

dump($personal->getRoles());
die();
```

there is nothing blank page.

Comment: not the current user i have selected a personal from my DB i want to see his roles ..

Comment: there is no error when i dow the dump($personal); i saw the personal and in twig i do the for role in personal.roles its ok.. my question how to do it in controller

Comment: you can test it there is in php

Comment: the dump function is in symfony2 use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper;

if (!function_exists('dump')) {
    /**
     * @author Nicolas Grekas <p@tchwork.com>
     */
    function dump($var)
    {
        foreach (func_get_args() as $var) {
            VarDumper::dump($var);
        }
    }
}

Comment: `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($personal);` might be of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    foreach( $personal->getRoles() as $role){
        echo $role;
    }
    die();
```

we must loop the getRoles()

Answer (score 8):

```
if(in_array('ROLE_ADMIN', $this->getUser()->getRoles())){
   //Is ADMIN !!!         
}
```